# Python - How to read image pixels without using third-party libraries?

Tags: python, image, data-structures, byte

Reading an image using opencv is as easy as:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread("image.png")
print(im)
```

That outputs a numpy array with the array items representing the image pixel values ranging from 0 to 255.

Is there a way to extract those same pixel values using the Python standard library? The expected output would be in the form of Python builtin data structures (i.e. lists/tuples/etc). For example:

```
[[191, 123, 100, 255],
 [233, 101, 120, 255]
 ...
]
```

What I have so far is this:

```
file = open("small.png", 'rb')
content= file.read()
print(content)
```

and that will produce a bytes object, but how do I get the actual pixel values of the image?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple solution to read pixels bytes from an image using the standard library.

You could certainly *write* such a module yourself, but that means understanding the PNG format, handling compressed image data, and so forth. By the time you're done, you have...developed your very own less capable version of [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

You are much better off using an existing module to get the data you want.